# Make a Sequence of Pictures with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

Recently, I often want to illustrate graph algorithms through a sequence of pictures as in

[image: Sequence of TikZ Pictures]

My current method to do this is to create a chain, and then place a nested `tikzpicture` in each node. As you can see, this breaks the node placement and spuriously tilts the trees (the intended behaviour is that all trees look the same up to the jumping of the red fill).

Currently, my best guess for the reason is the chains library, for if I replace the chain with some other means of placing the outer nodes, the trees get drawn correctly. So my question would be how to get the trees drawn correctly without sacrificing the ease of use of the chains library.

Here is the code to produce the above example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % Chain style
    start chain, 
    node distance = 1cm,
    every on chain/.style = {join},
    every join/.style = {->, draw=black, line width = 1pt},
]
\foreach \i in {1,...,3} {
    \node [on chain, rectangle, draw=black, dashed] {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            % Tree style
            cvertex/.style = {solid, circle, draw=black, line width=1pt, inner sep = 4pt}, 
            cedge/.style = {solid, draw=black, line width=1pt},
            edge from parent/.style = {cedge},
            level distance = 1cm, 
            sibling distance = 1cm, 
            %
            % Animation styles
            highlighted/.style = { fill = red },
            step base/.style = { o/.style={cvertex}, l/.style={cvertex}, r/.style={cvertex} },
            step 1/.style = {step base, o/.append style = {highlighted} },
            step 2/.style = {step base, l/.append style = {highlighted} },
            step 3/.style = {step base, r/.append style = {highlighted} },
            step \i
        ]
        \node [o] {}
            child { node [l] {} }
            child { node [r] {} }
        ; 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the internal picture same for all nodes (except color)?

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no.

Comment: So I take it as a no?

Comment: I'd prefer a general solution, but a hack for this special case could be useful as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why chains mess up the nodes in internal pictures and I feel there ought to be a simple solution, but here is an idea using the `pic` syntax of PGF 3.0. It essentially creates the illusion that the `pic` is on the chain, so it is possible to do something like:

```
\begin{scope}[start chain=going right, every join/.style={-stealth},
style 1/.style=, style 2/.style=, style 3/.style=]

\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
  \pic [style \i/.style={fill=red}] {graph={
    \node [style 1] {} child { node [style 2] {} }  child { node [style 3] {} };
  }};

\end{scope}
```

which would produce this:

[image]

The `pic` code is shown below with a somewhat more extreme example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, fit}
\begin{document}
\newbox\picbox
\begin{tikzpicture}[graph/.pic={
  \pgfinterruptpicture% 
  % Interrupt the picture and put the graph in a box.
  \global\setbox\picbox=\hbox{\pgfpicture%
     % Set default tree options
     \tikzset{every node/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0.0625cm}, 
       level distance=0.5cm, sibling distance=.5cm}%
      #1
    \endpgfpicture}%
  \endpgfinterruptpicture%
  % Put box in a separate node otherwise some parameters
  % (e.g., dashing) will be inherited by the picture in the \picbox.
  \node [on chain, join, outer sep=0pt] (@) {\copy\picbox}; 
  % Fit the dashed box around the existing box.
  \node [draw, fit=(@), inner sep=0pt, dashed] {};
}]

\begin{scope}[start chain=going right, every join/.style={-stealth}]

\pic {graph={
  \node [fill=red] {} child { node {} }  child { node {} };
}};

\pic {graph={
  \node {} child { node [fill=red] {} }  child { node {} };
}};

\pic [continue chain=going below] {graph={
  \node {} child { node {} }  child { node [fill=red] {} };
}};

\pic [continue chain=going left] {graph={
  \node {} child { node {} }  child { node {}
    child { node [fill=green] {} } child { node {} } };
}};

\pic [continue chain=going below] {graph={
  \node {} child { node {} }  child { node {}
    child { node {} } child { node [fill=blue] {} } };
}};

\pic [continue chain=going right] {graph={
  \node [fill=red] {}
    [level 2/.style={sibling distance=.25cm}] 
    child { node [fill=yellow] {}
      child { node [fill=pink]  {} }
      child { node [fill=green] {} }
    }
    child { node [fill=orange] {}
      child { node [fill=purple] {} } 
      child { node [fill=blue] {} } 
    };
}};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative using the new graphs stuff which must be compiled with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
 \usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right, every join/.style={->}]

\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
  \node [on chain, join, draw, dashed]{
    \tikz[solid]
      \graph [tree layout, nodes={circle, draw}, empty nodes, s\i/.style={/tikz/fill=red}] 
        { 1[s1/.try] -- {2[s2/.try], [s3/.try]3} }; };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This indeed solves the problem, although it has some bad smell since it involves code I don't understand (all those pgf commands). I guess I'll have to read up on those, but a simpler answer would still be preferable since I think my problem is common enough that there should be a clean and general interface to solve it.

Comment: @gTcV if you don't mind compiling with `lualatex` then the new graphs stuff doesn't seem to be affected by the use of chains. I've updated my answer to show an example.

Comment: Nice example, is there a way how to reference inner node of pic?